# How can I access the contents of a ZFS snapshot without affecting its current data?

Tags: zfs

I have a ZFS dataset which gets hourly snapshots taken.  Yesterday, a change was made to some of the files which needs to be reverted; however, the dataset has ongoing changes which shouldn't be reverted.

What are my options to access the snapshot without disturbing the current copy of its data?  Can I mount a snapshot in read-only mode to a new mount point?

Answer (score 21):

It's been a while since I played with zfs, but you should be able to use `zfs list -t snapshot` to find your available snapshots and access the files under a special `.zfs` directory under your zfs mountpoint.

```
[~]# zfs list -t snapshot
NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
mypool                    1.49G   527M   528M  /mnt/zfspool
mypool@snap1                28K      -   993M  -
mypool@snap2                28K      -   993M  -
mypool@snap3                28K      -   993M  -

[~]# cd /mnt/zfspool/.zfs/snapshot/snap1
[snap1]# ls
```

IIRC, snapshots are already read-only, so attempts to change data in the snapshot directory should fail.  If the data changes in the real fs, the snapshot should grow, as it copies the pre-changed data to keep the snapshot consistent.

You would need to `zfs clone` the snapshot to a new location, in order for you to make edits to the snapshot (at which point, it wouldn't be the snapshot any more).

As I said, though, it's been a while, so test first...

ref: http://www.googlux.com/zfs-snapshot.html

Comment: Yes, a ZFS snapshot is definitively read-only.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm using ZFS on Linux, but I don't see the .zfs folder under my pool's mount point

Comment: @STW - according to https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/forum/#!topic/zfs-discuss/Ktbndmd3rNo, you need ZoL 0.6.0rc8, on kernel > 2.6.37.  According to http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-fs/2008-November/005345.html, you need `zfs set snapdir=visible /mnt/zfspool` to make it visible, but you shouldn't need it to access your snapshot (i.e. you should be able to do `cd /mnt/zfspool/.zfs/snapsot/snap1` anyway)...

Comment: @STV you won't see .zfs but you can still cd into it. snapshots are stored in it's parent dataset so the parent dataset must be mounted in order to be able to access the .zfs

Comment: @mikky
you make my day

Comment: i unhid `.zfs`, per above, thanks, however `.zfs/snapshot` is empty.  so i still cant find my snapshots.

Comment: @BrianThomas - did you actually *take* a snapshot, and was it of a mounted filesystem (not a volume)?  If `zfs list -o name,mountpoint` shows *tank/yourfs* mounted at `/mnt/yourfs` and lists `yourfs@yoursnap`, then `ls /mnt/yourfs/.zfs/snapshot/yoursnap` should show the contents of */mnt/yourfs* as it was at the point of taking *yoursnap*.  I know that ZoL didn't implement the `.zfs` directory for a while, but has since 2012 (https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/commit/ebe7e575eae1e03b1faa545a424f008faeac589d).